# Lost window title bars and everything after selecting bad window theme in linux mint

Tags: linux, linux-mint

I've selected a window theme from the "Advanced Settings" in Linux Mint 12 which seems to be corrupted and I've lost everything on my desktop. I can't start any apps but I can open the terminal by right clicking on the desktop and selecting "Open in Terminal" but I am a Linux newbie and I don't how to use it.

It would help me much if you can answer only one of the two questions bellow: - How to start the "Advanced Settings" from the console ? or - How to revert to the default window theme using the console ?

Please keep in mind that I've got the problem when I changed the "Window Theme" not the "Shell Theme" in the Themes tab in the "Advanced Settings"

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is still interested, this is probably a problem with the window decorations. try opening a terminal and typing:

```
gtk-window-decorator --replace &
```